# ERROR - Syntax error in input (unexpected symbol "large")

Tags: haskell

I wrote this code , it is about if two strings are each anagram of another :

```
anagram :: String->String->Bool            
anagram w1 w2 = anagram1 x1 x2
where 
    y1 = break w1
    y2 = break w2
    x1 = quicksort y1
    x2 = quicksort y2


anagram1 :: [String]->[String]->Bool
anagram1 (h1:t1)(h2:t2)
    | h1!=h2 = False
    | h1==h2 = anagram1 t1 t2
    | otherwise = True
```

i found the code for quicksort there http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?QuickSortInHaskell

```
quicksort :: [String]->[String]
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (h:t) = quicksort small ++ (h : quicksort(large))
   where
      small = [y | y <- t, y <= h]
      large = [y | y <- t, y > h]


break :: String->[String]
break s = map (\c -> [c]) s
```

When i run it , i take error *Syntax error in input (unexpected symbol "large")* .

Why am i wrong ?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97a4e24a70de478d). You probably broke your indentation.

Answer (score 5):

If i load it into ghci it runs perfectly.

Maybe your indentation is incorrect in the where clause.

in `anagram` the where keyword must be indented and in haskell the "not equal" is `/=` and **not** `!=`

Please use spaces **everywhere**.

It has to be `YourModule.break` in `anagram` so it does not conflict with the `Prelude.break`.

Just read the error messages, the computer is trying to speak to you, so listen ;)

Test lots of code in GHCi and you'll get more comfortable with Haskell